# Setting to disable database logging in dblog without disabling module

Tags: 8, log-messages

I am going through the dblog core module, but I can't seem to find a setting to disable database logging. Is there an option to disable the database logging without disabling the module? 
Also, are the messages written in a file instead?

Comment: Database logging is the only purpose of this module. If you want a different logging destination install another module. Most popular is the core syslog module, but you find more in contrib.

Comment: Maybe to "disable" it you can override the service in charge to log an event, `logger.dblog`: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic-services